# Django project /admin Site matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am running a site live on heroku. My issuse occurs when I visit my site's admin located at www.mysite.com/admin. When I visit this page, I get

```
DoesNotExist at /admin/
Site matching query does not exist.
```

Thing is, my project /admin works locally as well as on my staging server. It just so happens when I visit it live, I get that error.

After looking around SOF, I tried doing running python manage.py shell with the following commands:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
Site.objects.create(pk=1, domain='www.xxx.com', name='xxx.com')
```

and I changed  SITE_ID = 1 to SITE_ID = www.mysite.com and that just ended up breaking my staging server, so I changed it back and tried again without changing the SITE_ID.

What could be the issue?

Comment: What database are you using locally? On Heroku? Have you synced the Heroku project with the database there?

Comment: Using sqlite3 locally and postgresql on heroku. I think that heroku is syned up if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: What happens if you run `heroku run python manage.py syncdb` ?

Comment: Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

Comment: SITE_ID takes an integer value for starters. I would also add your live projects url to the Sites and then when you are on a live environment, change the SITE_ID to the live url one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems the SITE_ID setting in your settings file is pointing to an ID that doesn't exist in your database.

You either need to create a new site in the sites model (via admin) and change the ID in the settings file to match that one, or re-insert the item via SQL and give it the same ID as your settings file.

Comment: Works perfectly, created one with `insert into "public"."django_site" ( "name", "domain") values ( 'site1', '0.0.0.0');` and edit the SITE_ID in settings to the right id

Answer (score 0):

This problem will always seem to occur continually, so if you don't want to serve your model with multiple sites, then I suggest you remove the SITE_ID from the setting file. Note this worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

I just had to **remove** the `'django.contrib.sessions'` from `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` as it was causing problems and I was using this project only for **one** site.

**However**, if you are using your project for multiple different sites and need the Django **sites** framework, please check `SITE_ID` in your database and if it matches the one defined in the settings.